# store url in same list with id php sql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

hi i want to store the url in the list loop that comes from db using primary key and foreign key but I don't know how to store the url in each list and have the same id in the first table and the second table what i want to do is something like this

```js
Array
(
    name : 'test',
    detail : 'detail',
    [url] => Array
        (
            [episode1] => Array
                (
                    [link] => https://
                )
            [episode2] => Array
                (
                    [link] => https://azeaze32a
                )

        )

)
```

i did all loops 'for,while,'foreach' and sat for a whole day but i fail every time this is my code:

```
<?php

$select_list_movies = select("SELECT * from list_movies");
$arr =[];
$i =0;
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_list_movies)) {
    $id = $rows['id'];
    //print_r($rows);
    $select_list_link = select("SELECT links.link FROM `list_movies`inner join links on list_movies.id = links.movie_id  where list_movies.id = '$id'");
    foreach ($select_list_link as $key1) {
        $i++;
        $arr = [
            'url' => ['episode'.$i => $key1]
        ];
    print_r($arr); // here print all url i want to put every links of every movie if there are links
    }
}

?>
```

If anything is not clear write your answer i'll reply to u if i can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're replacing `$arr` each time through the loop, you need to add to the `url` element.

```
<?php

$select_list_movies = select("SELECT * from list_movies");
$arr =['name' => 'test', 'detail' => 'detail', 'url' => []];
$i =0;
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_list_movies)) {
    $id = $rows['id'];
    //print_r($rows);
    $select_list_link = select("SELECT links.link FROM `list_movies`inner join links on list_movies.id = links.movie_id  where list_movies.id = '$id'");
    foreach ($select_list_link as $key1) {
        $i++;
        $arr['url']['episode'.$i] = $key1;
    print_r($arr); // here print all url i want to put every links of every movie if there are links
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: tysm really I'm stupid i didn't notice this way but i have a small question how can i return the index value If there is an example of a second table have other urls and it has other loops as an example cuz index keeps going up every time even in another table

Comment: You need to initialize `$i = 0;` before each loop to start from the beginning.

Comment: tysm! problem is solved